# array_mutisort function in PHP is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to sort an array by one of it's elements.
The array looks like this:

```
    <?php
    $activations = array();

    $activations[0] = array();
    $activations[0]['name'] = 'John Doe';
    $activations[0]['start'] = '2016-12-15T10:42:15';

    $activations[1] = array();
    $activations[1]['name'] = 'Jane Doe';
    $activations[1]['start'] = '2017-01-15T10:42:15';

    $activations[2] = array();
    $activations[2]['name'] = 'James Bond';
    $activations[2]['start'] = '2017-01-16T10:42:15';

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($activations);
    print '</pre>';

    $newactivations = array_mutisort($activations, SORT_DESC, 'start');

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($newactivations);
    print '</pre>';
    ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I get a fatal error on array_multisort
All I want is to have my original activations array sorted by the start column
Can this be done?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: First point to note: [array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is "pass by reference", and sorts the array you pass in; the returned value is a boolean success/failure flag

Comment: Second point: is the fatal error "Call to undefined function array_mutisort"?

Comment: what kind of output you want?

Comment: change array_mutisort to array_multisort

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes That will fix the fatal error, but it still won't sort it as desired.

Comment: see my code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using `usort` for this instead.

```
$activations = [
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'start' => '2016-12-15T10:42:15'],
    ['name' => 'Jane Doe', 'start' => '2017-01-15T10:42:15'],
    ['name' => 'James Bond', 'start' => '2017-01-16T10:42:15']
];

var_dump($activations);

usort($activations, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b['start'], $a['start']);
});

var_dump($activations);
```

Of course, if this array came from a database, using `ORDER BY start DESC` in the query that got them for you would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is the typo where you use `array_mutisort` instead of `array_multisort`. The second is your 3rd parameter being passed to that function, which should be a type flag (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)).

Furthermore, if you want to see the resulting array, it's `$activations` so you'll need to

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($activations);
print '</pre>';
```

rather than printing the boolean result of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, it's `array_multisort()` and you need to extract the `start` column and sort on that, then have `$activations` sorted:

```
array_multisort(array_column($activations, 'start'), $activations);
```

`SORT_ASC` is the default so use `SORT_DESC` if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
array_multisort($activations, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING);

$newactivations = $activations;
print '<pre>';
print_r($newactivations);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: I hope before you downvote you test first the code above